typescript import alias doesn't resolve import
I'am trying to create alias for using absolute paths. But I couldn't figure out how to run it properly. I have already try module-alias package but I think it doesn't work with es modules. I am always getting this error:
Package import specifier "#utils/math" is not defined in package /Users/alikocak/typetest/package.json imported from /Users/alikocak/typetest/dist/main.js
tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "ESNext",
      "target": "ESNext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "#utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
      }
    }
  }

package.json
{
  "name": "typetest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "export": "dist/main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node dist/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "imports": {
    "#utils/*": "./dist/utils/*"
  }


}


When I give full path its working but otherwise not. "#utils/*": "./dist/utils/math.js

I changed package.json imports to this:
"imports": {
    "#utils/*": "./dist/utils/*.js"
 }

Actually I tried this in first place but somehow it didn't work but now it works fine with that configuration.
